# Why do I get a timeout when using SqlCommand with date parameters?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlcommand

I'm having code similar to this:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2010, 12, 1);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2011, 12, 1);
string sql = "SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeDateColumn BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(connection)) {
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", startDate.Date);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", endDate.Date);

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
        // filling up some objects...
    }
}
```

This times out.

Just by changing the SQL query to include the dates in clear text, the query runs fine.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeDateColumn BETWEEN '" + startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' AND '" + endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
```

Using the Query Connection in VS2010, both queries runs fast, but as soon as i try it out in my program, the first one fails because it times out.

Is there an explanation to this behaviour, or have I just missed something?

Comment: What column type is SomeDateColumn? Because, you are sending in a "Date", but when the query parser parse 'YYYY-MM-DD' it can probably parse it as a DateTime, that might affect your indexes? Just a long shot. However, optimally it would be smart enough to convert the date if the index is based on another datatype.

Comment: Fire up the sql profiler and have a look at the query that is being executed.

Comment: @jishi - the column type is `datetime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the query optimizer of SQL Server is not considering the parameter values when it picks indexes.

As such, it does not know whether your `BETWEEN` clause would pick 1 row, 10 rows, or a bazillion rows, and thus picks a table-scan.

When you embed the dates as literals inside the SQL statement, the optimizer has all the information it needs in order to pick the right indexes.

What you can do is give [query hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx). If you know that the typical use-case for this query would involve a few rows, like for instance a span of a week, you can embed that knowledge into the SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeDateColumn BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
OPTION (
    OPTIMIZE FOR @StartDate = '<some date here>`,
                 @EndDate = '<some other date here>`
)
```

You should also ensure that statistics has been recalculated recently on the indexes involved on that table, to help the query optimizer pick useful indexes.

Comment: Please note that I'm not an expert on T-SQL. There may be some vastly better way to deal with this than the above, but from experience this has worked for me.

Comment: your post got me thinking, so i looked into available indices. i ended up using `WITH (INDEX(SomeTableIndex))` which included the date column.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the @enddate parameter. Shouldn't itr be like

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2010, 12, 1); 
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2011, 12, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether a query contains parameters or not will determine how the query optimiser generates an execution plan.  With literals it will generate the best plan for the supplied values with params it will generate the best plan for the values that could be supplied based on what i knows about the data in the table from the statistics.

Probably creating some statistics and indexes for those date columns will help improve the performance of the param query.